# Create function with n letter sequences

Tags: r

Hi I am struggling with a code problem in R

I want to create a function generate_lettersequences(n) that returns a list of n letter sequences, n between 1
and 26. The first vector is of length 1 and contains only the ‘a’, the second is of length 2 and consists
of the sequence ‘a’, ‘b’ and so on. The list elements should be named with letters in upper case (the last
letter in each vector). (with letters and LETTERS). The return value should be of class “lseqlist”.
Check the value of n at the beginning and yield an error message if needed (hint: use a construct like if
(condition) stop("errormsg")). Implement a print method that just informs about the total amount
of vectors.

Comment: I´m rather interested in the first half of the problem, mainly the dynamic list creation with numbers and Letters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part is very straightforward:

```r
generate_lettersequences <- function(n) {
  setNames(lapply(seq(n), function(x) letters[seq(x)]), LETTERS[seq(n)])
}
```

So, for example:

```r
generate_lettersequences(4)
#> $A
#> [1] "a"
#> 
#> $B
#> [1] "a" "b"
#> 
#> $C
#> [1] "a" "b" "c"
#> 
#> $D
#> [1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

A complete solution to the assignment would be:

```r
generate_lettersequences <- function(n) {
  if(n < 1 | n > 26) stop("'n' must be between 1 and 26")
  x <- setNames(lapply(seq(n), function(x) letters[seq(x)]), LETTERS[seq(n)])
  class(x) <- "lseqlist"
  x
}

print.lseqlist <- function(x, ...) {
  cat("An object of class 'lseqlist' containing", length(x), "vectors.\n")
}
```

Which allows the following behaviour:

```r
generate_lettersequences(27)
#> Error in generate_lettersequences(27) : 'n' must be between 1 and 26

lseq <- generate_lettersequences(4)
lseq
#> An object of class 'lseqlist' containing 4 vectors.

lseq[3]
#> $C
#> [1] "a" "b" "c"
```